# Box2D simulation super slow during vsync

Tags: physics, box2d, simulations

I've been developing my own game engine for the past few days and it's time to add physics. But before adding it in the editor itself, I opened a separate project and tried box2D with SDL2. I always remember to turn on vsync because it just does the FPS capping for you, but I've came over this problem where **Box2D simulation is slow when vsync is turned on (1.0f / 60.0f as the timestep), but it's normal when vsync is turned off (uses 30% CPU usage because FPS not capped)** I'd include the code sample below.

````
#include <Box2D/Box2D.h>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int,char**)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("FirstGame", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    
    b2World world(b2Vec2(0.0f, 9.81f));

    SDL_Rect rect = {0,0,100,100};

    b2Body* Body;

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(50.0f,50.0f);

    b2FixtureDef fdef;
    fdef.density = 1.0f;
    fdef.shape = &shape;

    b2BodyDef boxBodyDef;
    boxBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    boxBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f,0.0f);
    
    Body = world.CreateBody(&boxBodyDef);
    Body->CreateFixture(&fdef);

    bool close_game = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    
    while(close_game != true)
    {
        b2Vec2 pos = Body->GetPosition();
        
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                close_game = true;
        }

        rect.x = pos.x;
        rect.y = pos.y;
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer,&rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        
        world.Step(1.0f / 60.0f, 6.0f, 2.0f); // update
        
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
} 
```
````

Comment: What framerate are you getting when vsync is turned off? If it's much faster than 60 fps, then you'd expect the simulation to run visibly faster because you're still stepping the physics forward by 1/60 of a second, even if less than 1/60 of a second has truly passed in wall clock time — effectively running the physics in fast-forward.

Comment: Have you also run this with all the Box2d lines commented out to determine that the performance problem is coming from Box2d and not just a result of running SDL with those settings?